# What is the second argument in the code used to convert from string to int in Python?

Tags: python

I have found some strange syntax in python:

```
int(array[0], 32)
```

`array[0]` is some string, but what exactly is the second parameter for?  And can somebody please explain this `int()` syntax, is it function or casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Help on class int in module __builtin__:

class int(object)
 |  int(x[, base]) -> integer
 |
 |  Convert a string or number to an integer, if possible.  A floating point
 |  argument will be truncated towards zero (this does not include a string
 |  representation of a floating point number!)  When converting a string, use
 |  the optional base.  It is an error to supply a base when converting a
 |  non-string.  If base is zero, the proper base is guessed based on the
 |  string content.  If the argument is outside the integer range a
 |  long object will be returned instead.
```

So it is a base32 string you are parsing, with digits ranging from `0`..`9` and `a`..`v`.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int

```
int([x[, base]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is the base in which the conversion is to be made:

```
help(int)

class int(object)
 |  int(x[, base]) -> integer
....
```

Answer (score 1):

That's no casting, the second parameter specifies the base in which the number is expressed: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int

Answer (score 0):

Next time your run into similar problems 
try this:

```
>>> help (int)
```

Prints decimal value of binary number provided as string

```
>>> int('1010101011',2)
683
```

Prints decimal value of decimal number provided as string

```
>>> int('1010101011',10)
1010101011
>>>
```

Fails because we don't have symbol "2" in binary

```
>>> int('120000000',2) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '120000000'
```